# How to change the link in opencart for folder route

Tags: php

I have installed opencast 2.0.1.1. I have changed the brands to artist, but there is a problem when I open the artist page, the link still shows: 
`index.php?route=product/manufacturer` instead of 
`index.php?route=product/artist`.

In which files do I have to change?

Comment: Might be in "catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl" or in other file inside common folder

Comment: no there is no any link given for manufacturer in common folder or in header.tpl file it is inside product folder but in which file I have to change is a task

Comment: Then it must be a product controller.

Comment: Yes so could you please tell me in which I have to make changes to change the link

Comment: I will need to show your product controller page code, couldn't tell you like this. please update your question with product controller code

Comment: that's default opencart folders and there are so many files which file from opencart

Comment: Rename manufacturer method name with artist in product controller, enough